# How can keep a timed count of user input (from a button)?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 and a breadboard to make a morse code interpreter. The circuit is a simple button that lights up an LED when pressed. How could I use functions to count how long the button is held down?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given sufficient details of your circuit to pin this down to your particular use case, so I'll suggest the following (on which I'll base my code):

- Connect the LED (with series resistor) to GPIO 12
- Connect a 10k resistor between GPIO 11 and the 3.3V rail (acts as a pull-up)
- Connect the push-button between GPIO 11 and Ground (0V).

I'd then write the code to monitor the pin and log the time for each press into a list.  You can read out the values in the same order which allows you to process the times and interpret the code from them.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# set up an empty list for the key presses
presses = []

# set up the GPIO pins to register the presses and control the LED
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)

# turn LED off initially
GPIO.output(12, False)

while True:
    # wait for input to go 'low'
    input_value = GPIO.input(11)
    if not input_value:
        # log start time and light the LED
        start_time = time.time()
        GPIO.output(12, True)
        # wait for input to go high again
        while not input_value:
            input_value = GPIO.input(11)
        else:
            # log the time the button is un-pressed, and extinguish LED
            end_time = time.time()
            GPIO.output(12, False)
            # store the press times in the list, as a dictionary object
            presses.append({'start':start_time, 'end':end_time})
```

You'll finish up with a list that looks something like this:

> [{start:123234234.34534, end:123234240.23482}, {start:123234289.96841, end:123234333.12345}]

The numbers you see here are in units of seconds (this is your system time, which is measured in seconds since the epoch).

You can then use a for loop to run through each item in the list, subtract each end time from the start time, and of course subtract the start of the next press from the end of the previous one, so that you can assemble characters and words based on the gaps between presses.  Have fun :-)

Comment: Sorry, for not adding more information about my circuit, I believe I'm using a 1.6K ohm resistor, and running current from gpio 27 to 17 or vice versa. I had a minor breakthrough shortly after I posted this question, and was wondering if I could make a countdown timer of 4 seconds, make it run while the button is pressed, and declare the elapsed time as a variable. (ex: 1.3 seconds would be dot, and 1.4 - 2.8 seconds would be a dash)

Comment: I'd need a circuit diagram to see what you are doing there. However the elapsed time idea is another way of doing it. Don't forget the time between presses is important too. Counting up is easier than counting down, as it allows for pauses between words or characters.